# MVC rows with buttons that open dialog with autocomplete jquery not work from the second line

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I try to open modal dialog with autocomplete within from table.
when the modal opened from button in the first row, autocomplete fired.
but when try to open modal from the second row, **autocomplete not fired**.
the page look like that:
[table with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqfSt.png)
Click on replace button open modal like this : 
[modal with the autocomplete field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCBw4.png)

the HTML page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients.OrderBy(s => s.Line_no))
{
<tr>
<td>@item.Id</td>

<td><input data-toggle="modal" type="button" data-target="#@item.Id" value="Replace" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
<div class="modal fade" id="@item.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Replace Panel</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body clearfix">
                <p class="lead">
                    Do you Want to replace this ingredient @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)?
                </p>
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @*first row*@

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Current item", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                        @Html.Label("item", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ItemNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        </div>
                        @Html.Label("UOM", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.UOM, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                        @Html.Label("Qty", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @*first row*@
                    @*second row*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Replaced By", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @*@Html.Editor("SearchReplacedBy", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                            <input id="SearchReplacedBy" type="text" name="SearchReplacedBy" class="form-control" />
                            @Html.Hidden("ReplacedById")
                            @Html.Hidden("ReplacedBy")
                        </div>
                        @Html.Label("UOM", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.Editor("ReplacedByUOM", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                        @Html.Label("Quantity", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.Editor("ReplacedByQty", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @*second row*@
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer clearfix">

                <input name="Action" type="button" class="btn btn-group-xs btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" />
                <input name="Action" type="submit" class="btn btn-group-xs btn-success" value="Replace" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
}
```

the jquery code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#SearchReplacedBy').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetItemNames")',
        minLength: 3,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {

                $("#ReplacedBy").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#ReplacedById").val(ui.item.id);
                $("#ReplacedByUOM").val(ui.item.uom);
            }
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

What i miss ?? Please Help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to hit each input with autocomplete

```
$('input[name="SearchReplacedBy"]').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetItemNames")',
        minLength: 3,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {

                $('input[name ="ReplacedBy"]').val(ui.item.value);
                $('input[name ="ReplacedById"]').val(ui.item.id);
                $('input[name ="ReplacedByUOM"]').val(ui.item.uom);
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks to all for your help.